# SphinxRtdTheme undefined after making custom-named fork of sphinx_rtd_theme

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am working on a theme which is a fork of `sphinx_rtd_theme`. I renamed the theme so that people who would use the theme would not have to worry about overwriting their usual `sphinx_rtd_theme`.

However, when building documents using the custom theme, the `collapse_navigation` theme option is not respected. Other elements in `html_theme_options` are respected, however. And `collapse_navigation` is respected if I use `sphinx_rtd_theme` instead of my custom theme.

In the web console, I see

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: SphinxRtdTheme is not defined @http://localhost:1919/:522:11
j@http://localhost:1919/_static/jquery.js:2:29997
g/</k<@http://localhost:1919/_static/jquery.js:2:30313
 undefined

ReferenceError: SphinxRtdTheme is not defined[Learn More] localhost:1919:522:11
<anonymous> http://localhost:1919/:522
    jQuery 2
```

Which sort of makes sense - I did rename my theme and I believe these references should be `SphinxCustomRtdTheme` now. Except...

The only 2 (human-readable) references to `SphinxRtdTheme` in the core theme (https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme/search?q=SphinxRtdTheme&unscoped_q=SphinxRtdTheme) have already been changed to use my custom name, so it's not clear to me where `SphinxRtdTheme` exists in my theme at this point.

I've cleaned out the `/my_custom_theme/static/` folder already to force a rebuild of any Javascript, but to no avail.

I also tried renaming my `SphinxCustomRtdTheme` entries back to `SphinxRtdTheme`, but there was no change in the error.

Ideally, this error wouldn't exist, and then (also ideally) `collapse_navigation` would be respected properly for my theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my theme was being built into a separate version (dev0) than I expected, and thus it was perpetually stuck on a previous version. Updating everything to the current version removes the errors.